# Live unit testing stuck and cannot be stopped

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

Using Visual Studio 2017, with one of our solutions, live unit testing frequently gets stuck. In Test Explorer, it appears to be running tests (progress bar moving from left to right, "run" button is disabled), however, there is no "Cancel" button to stop the tests, and no actual progress is being made (a couple of dozen tests passed and then no more progress). The only way I found to get the test control back is to restart visual studio and reload the solution. It will become stuck again after while - do not know how or when because it runs in the background. The problem is only noticed when I want to run some tests and the "run test/debug test" context menu is disabled.

Is there a way to disable live unit testing completely (per solution or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can stop live unit testing from the top-level Visual Studio menu at:

Test -> Live Unit Testing -> Stop

Comment: That options is not available when the problem happens.

Comment: After pushing the 'stop' button it'll keep on stopping forever.

[![Snapshot of issue][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBd0u.png